# Loading Process- Different UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app I have a UIButton and when you tap it I have a UIActivityIndicatorView and I want to add diffrent UI Labels as it loads. Its actually not a real loading process its just for looks.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Create a custom UIView (u can xibs if you want). That view should have second UIView as a container in it. When you init the view set it to be the same size as the viewController you are putting it in. Its background color is transparent (or black with a lower alpha if you want to have the greyed out effect). Set the container to be the actual size you want it to appear.

Step 2:

Put a UIActivityIndicatorView and a UILabel in the container. Lay it out how you like.

Step 3:

Write a label updating method that uses a timer. Either performSelector:afterDelay: or dispatch_after. Have this method set the label text, wait a period of time, change then text, wait a period of time, change it again and so on.

Step 4:

Write showIndicator() and hideIndicator() methods. The view and the container's hidden property should be set to true. When showIndicator() is called set the hidden to false and call the label updating method from step 3. When you've reached the end of all your label changes then set everything back to hidden = true

It should work like this. The view controller loads up and adds this view. The view takes up the entire screen but you cant see anything because it is hidden by default. The user hits the button and showIndicator() method is called. The view become visible. Although it takes up the entire screen it appears to be a small overlay because the background is transparent (or back with an alpha for the greyed out look) and the container has a smaller frame and a solid color. The delayed methods are also called now and it changes the label, waits, changes it and so on. When you reach the end of the sequence hideIndicator() is called and all views are set back to hidden = true. Good Luck!!!